# remove blue color from JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

It's the first time i'm using a JTabbedPane. It seems that default look and feel display an blue border border over the tab and around the component itself. How can i disable that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one easy and fast way you can remove this "effect" by setting the LookAndFeel to the SystemLookAndFeel (or any other lookandfeel):

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Please, read this article so you can understand more about that subject: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 0):

## Change Look And Feel with "UIManager"

```
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled+Pressed].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+MouseOver+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+Pressed+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.GRAY));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[MouseOver+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Pressed+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
```

## BackgroundPainter class

```
public class BackgroundPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {

private Color color = null;

BackgroundPainter(Color c) {
    color = c;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {
    if (color != null) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
    }
}
```

}